# Mail at random time

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Maryanne's mail arrives at a random time between 1 p.m. and 3 p.m. Maryanne chooses a random time between 2 p.m and 3 p.m. to go check her mail. What is the probability that Maryanne's mail has been delivered when she goes to check on it?

I solved it geometrically constructing a cartesian plane with the restrictions of the problem and imposing that Maryanne's checking of the mail was after the delivering of it. The solution with this approach is 3/4. However I'm trying to solve this problem in another way without using a plane where to count dimensions of areas. But I'm a bit stuck, Which can be an idea?

Comment: Hint:  let $t\in [0,1]$ be the time, after $2:00$ that she checks.  Argue that the probability that the mail is there at that time is $\frac 12+\frac t2$.

Comment: I think that my alternate reasoning is similar to this but then I don't know how to go on , how can i estimate t?

Comment: Estimate what?  What you have computed the probability for a specific time $t$, all you have to do is to integrate over the possible times.  Note;  this is more or less the same as what appears in the posted solution from @SiongThyeGoh .  Different units are used for the time, but that's an easy substitution.

Comment: ok but if I don't want to use integrals?

Comment: Well, the "integral" in question is the area of a triangle...pretty straight forward.  Otherwise, I don't know what to say....it's a continuous probability.  Sooner or later you have to do something equivalent to the integral.

Comment: ok I got it ,thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the time that the mail arrive and let $Y$ be the time that Maryanne check her mail.

$X \sim Uni(1,3)$ and $Y \sim Uni(2,3)$,

\begin{align}
P(X \le Y) &= \int_1^3 P(X \le Y|X=x) f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_1^2 P(X \le Y|X=x) f_X(x) \, dx  + \int_2^3 P(X \le Y|X=x) f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \frac 12\int_1^2 P(X \le Y|X=x) \, dx +  \frac12 \int_2^3 P(X \le Y|X=x)  \, dx \\
&=\frac12 + \frac12 \int_2^3 (3-x) \, dx
\end{align}

Use a substitution and you should be able to find the solution.